# TinyMCE custom plugin, how to make a word automatically selected based on current cursor position?

Tags: tinymce, plugin-tinymce

Making a custom plugin for TinyMCE, I wonder how to make a word automatically selected based on current cursor position, like in the the Wordpress "Add link" plugin.

I've searched the WP TinyMCe Wplink code and TinyMCE Docs but I've got no reference....

Comment: did you solve this? Also wondering.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't...